# Tree structure segmentation fault

Tags: c

Segmentation fault (core dumped), please help. I don't understand what I did wrong. The code compiles but I get the error above. I understand that the code tries to access memory that it can't, but I don't see where it is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int freq[256] = {0};

struct Node
{
  unsigned char m_ch;
  int m_freq;
  struct Node *m_ls,*m_rs;
  struct Node *m_hls,*m_hrs;
};

struct Node* createNode(int freq,char ch);
void insertTree(struct Node **root,struct Node * n);
struct Node* getBinTree(FILE *fsrc);
void inorder(struct Node *root);

int main()
{
  FILE *fsrc;
  struct Node *tree=NULL;
  fsrc = fopen("src.txt","rb");
  tree=getBinTree(fsrc);
  inorder(tree);
  return 1;
}


struct Node* createNode(int freq,char ch)
{
    struct Node *pNode=NULL;
    pNode->m_freq=freq;
    pNode->m_ch=ch;
    return pNode;
}

void insertTree(struct Node **root,struct Node *n)
{
  if(!(*root))
  {
    *root=n;
    return;
  }
  if(n->m_freq<(*root)->m_freq)
  {
    insertTree(&(*root)->m_ls,n);
  }
  else
  {
    insertTree(&(*root)->m_rs,n);
  }
}

struct Node* getBinTree(FILE *fsrc)
{
  struct Node *temp=NULL;
  struct Node **root=NULL;
  int c,i;
  while ((c = fgetc(fsrc)) != EOF)
  {
    freq[c]++;
  }
  freq[255]=1;
  fclose(fsrc);
  for(i=0;i<256;i++)
  {
    if(freq[i]>0)
    {
      temp=createNode(freq[i],i);
      insertTree(root,temp);
    }
  }
}

void inorder(struct Node *root)
{
if(root != NULL)
   {
     inorder(root->m_ls);
     printf(" %d\n",root->m_freq);
     inorder(root->m_rs);
   }
   return;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger ?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>   struct Node *pNode=NULL;
>   pNode->m_freq=freq;
> ```

One of the reasons is dereferencing the NULL pointer in the quoted code block above.

Memory must be allocated before using the pointer. Like this:

```
struct Node *pNode = malloc (sizeof *pNode);
```

Comment: Indeed there isn't a single `malloc()` or `calloc()` or even `realloc()` in the code.